# Recommended TCP buffer size? Recommended to break it up?

Tags: java, c#, xml, buffer

I am writing an application which grabs an XML file from the server and then works with the data inside. My question is, because TCP ensures that all packets arrive and is beyond my control to control how it breaks that data apart, does it make sense to cap the buffer size? If so, I can send the data over in chunks and reassemble them on the client side. Obviously I cannot make an infinite buffer. The XML can get fairly large, up to 256kb and I am bit worried about reserving a buffer of that size. The data is pulled by an Android device but we can assume the device have 1gb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The TCP receive buffer size has nothing to do with the size of the data being transferred. Obviously, you can transport gigabytes of data over TCP streams and that doesn't require the buffer to be of the same size. The buffer size generally has to do with performance (both network and processor on the endpoints) and can be small - you probably don't have to change the default settings in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reassemble it at the client side yourself. Just attach an XML parser directly to the socket InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

The default buffers in the network stack are generally tuned to be good, on average. Unless your application is particularly unusual (which it does not sound like), you would be better off not changing the buffer size. The fact that the endpoints are different will also result in tension that prevents easy selection of anything more optimal for both simultaneously.

As suggested, if you use a streaming parser on the receiving side, the buffer size does not really matter. Send the messages as you have them ready to reduce latency caused by batching the entire document.